# Air purfier to save on air conditionig?

Tags: air-conditioning, air-quality

We have to renovate an apartment on a low floor in a busy area and an expert advised us to install an air purifier system.

He said that these tools are beyond the relief they are entitled to air conditioning systems and the costs would be similar. According to him the air purifying systems tends to lower the temperature of 3/4 degrees also removing moisture.

Given that at present we have no air conditioning system but we thought of making the preparation, do you think a system of this type could help to save on air conditioning?

The engine of the system will be located outside the apartment on the balcony, and inside there will be the tubes and a mouth in each room. By now we have no decive on the model of the system, it was just a proposal

Comment: Can you provide more details on the proposed system (make and model numbers would be useful)?

Answer (score 2):

No. You're being sold a big scam. Where is the heat going? If it's a machine that generates electricity inside and has no connection to the outside, it's going to *increase* the amount of heat in the building. If it's an HRV or ERV system that exchanges and filters outside air, that's a different kettle of fish, but those systems are also not going to cool the house at all.

If you want it cooler in your apartment, consider actual cooling systems, better shading, radiant barriers, or more insulation.

Answer (score 2):

You need to give us an example of an air purifier model that person proposes to install. But, generally speaking, air purifiers do not lower temperature or extract moisture. And I am not sure how economical this would be since a good air purifier with ducts is an order of magnitude more expensive than an apartment-size window AC unit.

I would consider an air purifier as an add-on to an AC system if it used the same ducts.

What does this phrase mean, "these tools are beyond the relief they are entitled to air conditioning systems"?